# Need to disable scroll on html page without page shift?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML page on click of button i am displaying a Popup made on same page as div.
On displaying that popup i need to disable the scrollbar of the parent page.
Presently i am doing this:

```
/* Function to disable parent page scrollbar */
function DisableParentPageScroll(){
    $('body,html').css('overflow-y','hidden');
}

/* Function to enable parent page scrollbar */
function EnableParentPageScroll(){
    $('body,html').removeAttr("style");
}
```

But when i am disabling the page there is a page shift observed. How can i prevent this?

Comment: What do you mean by pages-shift? You can do one thing, on clicking, first save the current scroll-position of the scroll-bar, after the user confirms, restore the page to that position, and after that you set the overflow to hidden.

Comment: Do you mean the shift when the scrollbar disappears?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term which you are using **Page Shift**, its occurring because you are removing the scrollbar and when the scroll bar is removed the space becomes empty and then the design document gets more space and hence its shifting. If you want to avoid this you have to add some `Padding or Margin` to the external wrapper or `<body>`.

For e.g. like this

```
/* Function to disable parent page scrollbar */
function DisableParentPageScroll(){
    $('html').css('overflow', 'hidden'); // Added this for few browsers
    $('body').css({
        'overflow-y':'hidden',
        'padding-right': '20px' // Asuming the scrollbar width as 20px
     });
}

/* Function to enable parent page scrollbar */
function EnableParentPageScroll(){
    $('html').removeAttr('style'); // Added this for few browsers
    $('body').css({
        'overflow-y':'auto',
        'padding-right': '0'
     });
}
```

Comment: What about the page moving up. Actually when i scroll down the page and open popup the parent page goes back to top because i am making overflow as hidden. is there any work around that?

Comment: are you making the page to overflow hidden when the popup opens? if not please share the requirement.

Comment: Yes i am making page to overflow hidden when the popup opens. But the parent page scrolls back to the top of the page if I open the popup from bottom of the page. I want that parent page should remain at the same position when overflow is made hidden.

Comment: If you make it overflow:hidden then this problem would arise. Why are you making the parent page to overflow: hidden any specific reasons can you let me know. So that I can tell you if there is any other solution.

Comment: Actually on popup display i don't want to make parent page scroll bind.